# Review Late Answers are too late and sometimes on closed questions, why?

Tags: bug

I keep getting "Late Answers" on my [review tab](https://ux.stackexchange.com/review) on answers that are a year or older, and even on already closed questions. So I edit - and the closed question comes right back at the top again. That can't be right - can it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just catching older and older posts in the queue; the initial oldest post date it would grab was intentionally conservative so Stack Overflow wouldn't be insanely swamped with posts: [they look farther in the past every month](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/150080/why-does-the-late-answer-review-queue-sometimes-spike-in-size-by-over-5000) and will eventually cover all posts. Just another weird thing we have to put up with to accommodate SO's scale on the same engine.

Not sure what you mean about the question coming back to the top again though. Posts you've reviewed should be removed from your queue.

Comment: Thanx Ben. I mean when I edit they move to the top of the active questions list (start page of UX.SE) - not my review list.

Comment: If you make any edits to questions / answers then it automatically 'bumps' that question to the top of the list of questions on the front page. Same as if you add tags to the post. The /questions list is the only date-ordered section, the front page is for currently active posts (of which edits count as being active)

Comment: @JonW Ture that, but is it handled the right way - or should we list questions based on another algorithm than *most recent activity*?

Comment: @BennySkogberg most recent makes a lot of sense except when doing cleanup of old posts...why miss a great answer to an old question just so we avoid seeing some old, minor cleanup from time to time?

Comment: @BenBrocka Didn't think of it in that way. And I have to say - you have convinced me here. Thank you for that! :-)